# Unable to copy file. Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, svn

I am working on asp.net 3.5 project on remote machine. I am accessing it using remote desktop. When I build the project, I get error:

```
Error   62  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\myprojname.pdb" to "bin\myprojname.pdb". Access to the path 'bin\myprojname.pdb' is denied.
```

Project is under SVN. I deleted the obj\Debug\myprojname.pdb and tried to run again but getting same error. I am trying to remove thereadonly from the folder but after clicking ok, It becomes readonly again ( i guess because of SVN).

Comment: Have you tried locking the file and then executing?

Comment: @Amit yes I tried but It doesn't show me to lock option on pdb file.

Comment: if you don't have any important files in 'bin', just delete the whole folder to solve the problem, i think. or perhaps 'bin\myprojname.pdb' is locked by another user? (just a comment)

Comment: Hi Paul. thanks for your response. I deleted the pdf file but When I run project, It creates the file and I get same error.

Comment: You don't need to add the /bin and /obj folders to source control. Just remove them from svn.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I solved this problem by deleting the contentious files from bin folder and rebuilding the project.

Comment: For me, windows doesn't allow to delete any files or folders in the bin folder, not even bin folder itself. For around 1-2 mins.

Comment: @ Mitulát báti 1-2 minutes is perhaps the time while VS was still building your project/solution, and hence you were not allowed to delete these files. If this is not the case, check if there more instances of the same project/solution open/running. HTH :).

Comment: I usually cancel my build when it takes more than 2 seconds to start at all, so I don't think that's the case. Anyway thank you for your answer. And in the meantime I found that renaming the file always works (for me at least). So Studio can make a new build then, without any problems. :-)

Comment: Maybe when renaming itself works then deleting may work, I didn't observed that. And of course today I can't reproduce this not-working-building-madness.

Comment: I got a bunch of these after a merge to a seldom used branch. The initial clean and build on this branch produced these errors. Without doing anything, I ran a Rebuild and that got these access denied errors down to one XML file. I right-clicked that XML file in the Solution Explorer and selected the "contentious" XML file and deleted it. I then ran the Rebuild again and Ta-Dah!, no errors. Thanks for suggesting this fix for this problem.

Comment: Yes that may solve the problem once, but how do you solve it on an ongoing basis. No one wants to have to manually delete files each time they build. The answer could be fleshed out a bit better by noting "dotnet clean xxx.sln" as a way of achieving this.

Answer (score 44):

I solved it by Unchecking the `Read-only` CheckBox option on folder setting.

Comment: Same thing happened in my case. I have no idea why the whole containing folder has been marked as read-only

Comment: @WahidBitar, I agree with you. Mine is kind of a crude solution which helped me at that time, and I put it here to save others from the same hassle. I believe the better solution will be one of these two steps if needed: (1) Not to check in bin folder to source control, thereby removing the the Read-Only constraint on the bin files (2) As this answer suggested, uncheck the REad-only setting on the problematic files

Comment: Created a Visual Studio Extension for clearing ReadOnly and Hidden attribute of dlls which blocking the build. 
UnBlockDllExtension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NithinVR.UnBlockDllExtension

Comment: @vrnithinkumar I cannot attach vs for debugging now because of your extension. Don't install this extension.

Comment: **BEST ANSWER**

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I only had to restart the visual studio. 
Classic move :)

Answer (score 6):

I started Visual studio as administrator and that worked.

Answer (score 5):

Removed read only flag on whole solution and it worked. Visual Studio 2012+TFS 2013

Answer (score 4):

For me, my issue was that my AntiVirus had a handle on the referenced .dll that was used in my solution. Not exactly sure why, plan on researching it later. But killing my AV Service that had the handle, then restarting Visual Studio fixed this issue for me.

Hope this helps those of you who are maybe having to restart your entire PC when this happens, as before I figured this out, it was the only fix to my solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails try a reboot of your computer - only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue with WebActivator.dll

Closing VS and reopening resolved the issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Just found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af9ef480-a2ac-4cca-ab73-646fb387f8d3/unable-to-copy-file-to-bindebugfilenamepdb-access-to-the-path-bindebugfilenamepdb-is?forum=tfsbuild), which worked for me:

Make sure `bin` isn't checked in to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by Unchecking the Read-only CheckBox option on folder setting.than reload the solution again :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the corresponding reference(.dll file) from the References and add it back again using add reference option.I got a similar error,and i have solved it this way.I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the options below, the only solution was **to restart the Windows 7**.

- *Removed read only flag.*
- *Restart the visual studio.*
- *Remove the corresponding reference(.dll file) from the References and add it back*
- *Make sure bin isn't checked in to TFS*
- *Deleting the contentious files from bin folder*

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by excluding my bin folder from my project in VS 2012. Right click on the BIN folder and select "Exclude From Project".

Answer (score 0):

**If you only get this for select files**:

1. Go to Published file folder
2. Select the problem Files
3. Properties
4. **Uncheck Read-Only**

Apparently this can occur when **Source Control non-checked out files are read only, and then someone just copies specific files**.

*(I tried other people's suggestions: giving myself write access to wwwroot, running VS as admin, but for me it was the read-only that did the trick.  I specify this answer to point out it is the files at the destination you are trying to publish to.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have done some check-in into the bin folder then this issue will come.
Just delete that file and check-in again and build it. It will definitely work.
**Note: Please don't check-in anything into bin folder**

Answer (score 0):

the error is pretty obvious there
Access to the path 'bin\myprojname.pdb\' is denied.
the user the web console process is running under (not the user you created in the webconsole, the actual windows user), most likely "Network Service" doesnt have permissions to that folder.

You can either
- Right click on that folder, goto permissions and add the "Network Service" user
- Right click on that folder, goto permissions and add the "Everyone" user

that should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might be opened two visual studios for two different solutions. Vs-A is in Debug mode and VsB is erroring out about .pdb file access denied. So remove the debug mode from Vs-A and Rebuild Vs-B. It should work now, without errors.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by cleaning all projects individually and then rebuilding them individually in the order of their dependency over each other

Answer (score 0):

Suprisingly, using

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

was the reason the project failed to compile for me with the same error message. Converting to

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

solved it.
Command line application, .NET 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Tip for VS noobs like me: Check you're looking at the right /bin folder.

Details: To me, "Failed to copy from SomeDependancy/bin/Debug to /bin" sounds like it means the destination is SomeDependancy/bin. But in my application it meant MainProject/bin. I cottoned on to the idea when I discovered I could build the dependencies and only MainProject was failing. I haven't completed testing yet, but it looks like the suggestion about recreating the folder might now work for me.