# C# File.Copy access denied error

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to copy files from nunit test build folder to nunit runtime folder but getting

> Access denied error

I have a folder path setup like `Testproject/bin/debug/something.config` and tried the options below but its not working for me.

- Deleted the bin folder and then rebuilt it.
- Opened closed VS.
- Deleted bin folder created new bin folder manually.
- Tried to remove readonly in folder option but it again gets set to
  readonly.

I found these worked for others in the thread 
[Unable to copy file. Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750101/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

I am also using SVN as source control.

Comment: Did you check if this file is taken by SVN?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the files by hand, or are they copied during a test? If the latter, try the former, and also check that you are appropriately closing any file handles you have in the test.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you haven't tried is to run Visual Studio as an administrator.  Right click on it, and select `run as administrator`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it was locked and abandoned.

I've used [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/) to unlock files that Windows so often locks and abandons. Even after rebooting the files can sometimes remain locked by a process that no longer exists.

It will also tell you what applications have locked the file.