# Solution opened in VS 2013 and VS 2010 simultaneously no longer builds locally in VS2012 or VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio 2010, 2012 and 2013 Ultimate installed on my Windows 7 machine. I typically open and work with my project in VS2012 unless I need to run unit tests which seem to work better in VS2010. So I was able to build locally with these fine until recently when I installed VS2013 and opened the project to work, I was debugging a separate issue which caused me to open the solution in VS2013 and VS2010 at the same time. The project is tracked through TFS 2012. Now I can only build locally with VS2010; if I attempt to build in VS2012 or VS2013 I get a lot of errors, the first being a permission error which I think is the root cause:

> Error 38  Unable to copy file "C:\Users\first.last\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Main\Development\GlobalServices\LoaderLibrary\XmpToolkit.dll" to "bin\Release\XmpToolkit.dll". Access to the path 'bin\Release\XmpToolkit.dll' is denied.

Doing some online searches points me to delete the specific file it's speaking about but I have tried this to no avail. Is it possible opening the solution twice in different versions of Visual Studio screwed up my path permissions?

Update: Closing the IDE's may work for some but has not resolved my issue.  I can however build as DEBUG but not as RELEASE.  Still unsure why this is.

Update 2: I had to close Visual Studio, navigate to my solutions parent directory in Windows Explorer, un-check the parent solution folder read-only property including recursive folders.  Reloading the solution and performing a rebuild then succeeded.

[Further troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750101/unable-to-copy-file-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files are cross-referenced in different versions of visual studio, each running simultaneously. This is extremely error-prone and WILL break everything - permission-errors are only the beginning. NEVER open more than 1 IDE if you're working on the same configsets, solutions.

To solve your problem you simply need to close two of the IDEs - one of them is currently scanning or even prematurely locking your files, causing these errors.

Comment: I've tried this, I've closed all instances of visual studio, restarted my computer. Still I can only build locally with 2010.

Comment: in that case you need to re-set all of your permissions on all of the affected files - you might set them recursively via selecting the parent folder and tick the appropriate checkbox for application to sub-elements. Close your IDEs BEFORE you do that and try again

Comment: YESSSSSS IT'S WORKING!  It was necessary to modify the solutions parent directory permissions and recursive folders/files for the build to succeed.